# How to use netbeans module in my own project?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, wizard, formwizard

I hvae done a [netbeans tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html) to create a wizard dialog, and the result wizard dialog module have appear on the toolbar of my netbeans, but the problem is how could I use that module in my own project.
[image]

I created a new project called 'testDemo' and copied all the source code of the module, then I tried to create a instance of that wizard dialog, but failed with 'org.openide could not found'.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required JARs may be found in the NetBeans distribution. On my platform, the NetBeans directory is inside the application bundle itself:

```
$ cd /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources
$ find NetBeans -name \*openide-util\*jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar
NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/locale/org-openide-util-enumerations_ja.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/locale/org-openide-util-enumerations_pt_BR.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/locale/org-openide-util-enumerations_zh_CN.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/org-openide-util-enumerations.jar
NetBeans/platform/update/backup/netbeans/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar
NetBeans/platform/update/backup/netbeans/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar
NetBeans/platform/update/backup/netbeans/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar
$ find NetBeans -name \*openide-awt\*jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/locale/org-openide-awt_ja.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/locale/org-openide-awt_pt_BR.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/locale/org-openide-awt_zh_CN.jar
NetBeans/platform/modules/org-openide-awt.jar
```