# How to add a Netbeans Wizard module to own project?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, wizard

My question is simillar to topic:

[How to use netbeans module in my own project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535510/how-to-use-netbeans-module-in-my-own-project) 

but I have problem with invoking created wizard.
I have copied wizard sources and libraries to my own project. 

Now I want to call a wizard after clicking some button in my application (code for buttons action performed method below - it is generated by Netbeans):

 `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

      DemoWizardAction d =  new DemoWizardAction();
      d.actionPerformed(evt);
    }` 


So now, after button's click wizard's frame is invoked, but it disappears when I click "next" button (it should go to a second wizard's frame).

Could somebody help how to call wizard properly?

Answer (score 0):

I also hat the problem that my wizard disappeared. This used to happen because the `Trivial` implementation of `DialogDisplayer` closes the dialog once a button is clicked.

My solution: Do not use the `notify()` method.

My code example:

```
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
  final List<WizardDescriptor.Panel<WizardDescriptor>> panels = new ArrayList<WizardDescriptor.Panel<WizardDescriptor>>();
  panels.add(new WizardPanel());
  panels.add(new WizardPanel2());
  final String[] steps = new String[panels.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < panels.size(); i++) {
    final Component c = panels.get(i).getComponent();
    // Default step name to component name of panel.
    steps[i] = c.getName();
    if (c instanceof JComponent) { // assume Swing components
      final JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
      jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_SELECTED_INDEX, i);
      jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_DATA, steps);
      jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_AUTO_WIZARD_STYLE, true);
      jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_DISPLAYED, true);
      jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_NUMBERED, true);
      // jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_IMAGE,
      // ImageUtilities.loadImage("com/skytron/pvgw/icons/logo40.png", true));
      // jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_IMAGE_ALIGNMENT, "South");
    }
  }

  final WizardDescriptor wiz = new WizardDescriptor(
      new WizardDescriptor.ArrayIterator<WizardDescriptor>(panels));
  // {0} will be replaced by WizardDesriptor.Panel.getComponent().getName()
  wiz.setTitleFormat(new MessageFormat("{0}"));
  wiz.setTitle("...dialog title...");

  // this does not work outside of netbeans!!!
  // if (DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notify(wiz) ==
  // WizardDescriptor.FINISH_OPTION) {
  // do something
  // }

  // create a dialog and set it visible.
  final Dialog wizardDialog = DialogDisplayer.getDefault().createDialog(wiz);
  wizardDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```